# Redirect user for specific time and return

Tags: javascript

My aim is to redirect user to a specific website for 18 seconds and then redirect back to my website. To accomplish this, I have written the code below. The problem I am facing was that the website started to redirect in a loop so I had to come up with a condition to avoid that. For this I have putted a check if the user is coming from my redirected website or not but now the redirection isnt working at all. Please guide. Thanks

Note: startupsandfinance is the domain name from which the user gets redirected back.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if !(( document.referrer.search(&quot;startupsandfinance&quot;))){


                        document.cookie=&quot;toURL&quot;+ &quot;=&quot; +escape(document.URL)+&quot;;path=/; domain=.mycsnippets.com&quot;;
                        document.cookie=&quot;refURL&quot;+ &quot;=&quot; +escape(document.referrer)+&quot;;path=/; domain=.mycsnippets.com&quot;;
                        this.location=&#39;http://www.startupsandfinance.com/welcome.htm&#39;;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Why redirect? Don't you want the user to stay on your site?

Comment: For some extra bucks..

Comment: I doubt your visitors will like it :-/

Comment: I know but don't have another option to make some extra bucks for now :/

Answer (score 2):

> Please guide

- `if !((` is a syntax error
- `!search()` will not work, since `search` returns `-1` when nothing is found and the index else
- Do not use `this.location`, but `window.location`
- No need to use entity escapes inside `<script>` tags
- Do never ever rely on `referer`, it can easily be spoofed or is disabled. Use cookies instead: Before redirecting set it, when coming back you can check it.